# Post replication powershell script - on subscriber

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I need to execute a command before a replication executes on the publisher, and after, on the subscriber.

I seem to have it working on the publisher, by adding another step in the replication agent.

But i have yet to discover how i can execute another step on the subscriber.
I't has to be possible to somehow trigger a job on the subscriber, after a replication has succeded.

Do anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: This is snapshot replication I take it?
If that's the case then why not schedule a step after replication that uses SQLCMD or Invoke-SQLCmd to run exec sp_start_job on the remote server?

Comment: As long as the command is executed on the remote server / publisher :) This seems like a fine solution to the issue. Could you by any chance post an answer with a little more detail?

Comment: Does it matter what type of replication it is?

Comment: Yes. Snapshot replication will execute and then stop, whereas transactional replication will not stop executing (as it will continue to apply transactions on the remote server).
Or are you just refering to the you needing to run processes before and after the snapshot (or if the replication job fails)?

Comment: I need to execute a command whenever a replication starts and finishes. Currently i have setup transactional replication, but i guess i can still execute the snapshot agent and then execute the job. I just need it to happen as often as possible.

Comment: Is it correct that i can run transactional replication and then still execute the snapshot agent to replicate using a snapshot? Thanks :)

Comment: Transactional replication job execution is ongoing, but you can schedule the snapshot as often as you like. It will not actually take a snapshot if nothing has been reinitialized, but you still go through all the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another job step to the snapshot agent which runs sqlcmd with what ever T-SQL command needs to be run using the -S parameter to specify to connect to the remote SQL Server.

Comment: I need to execute a job on the remote server, which then executes a powershell remoting script.

Comment: Then have the job on the publisher run sqlcmd -S Subscriber -Q "exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @name='What ever the name is'" and have the job on the subscriber be the PowerShell.  That or have the job on the subscriber just run the PowerShell script remotely.

Comment: This is all working quite nice! Thanks
How is security when using "sqlcmd -S"?

Comment: -S tells you the server name.  By default it's using Windows Auth.  -U {username} -P {password} will use SQL Auth if needed.